# What's the Python equivalent of C++'s "a = f++;", if any?

Tags: python, syntax

In C++, two things can happen in the same line: something is incremented, and an equality is set; i.e.:

```
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int f = 2;
    a = f++; // a = 2, f = 3
    return 0;
}
```

Can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, by using multiple assignment targets:

```
a, f = f, f + 1
```

or by just plain incrementing `f` on a separate line:

```
a = f
f += 1
```

because readable trumps overly clever.

There is no `++` operator because integers in Python are immutable; you rebind the name to a new integer value instead.

Answer (score 4):

No var`++` equivalent in python.

```
a = f
f += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no increment operators in Python. Try:

```
a, f = f, f+1
```

This notation yields the same result as this one:

```
a = f
f = f+1
```

Notice how the parts in the left and right of `=` signs are grouped in the first code.

Comment: `f = f` Is it a typo?

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't know this notation. I understand now, `A = B` and `C = D` can be written as `A, C = B, D`. Sorry for the downvote.